# Removing dialogues from a movie script and only keeping event structures using python

Tags: python-2.7

I have to rewrite a movie script with only event structures to be used later in Natural Language Processing. Will have to change almost 20 scripts.

For example:

```
      The young RIDER dashes over to help, trembling when he sees 
      who his board has hit.

                             RIDER
                Hey -- sorry.

      Cowering in fear, he attempts to scoop up her scattered 
      belongings.

                             KAT
                Leave it 

      He persists.
```

This must be changed to: 
*The young RIDER dashes over to help, trembling when he sees 
          who his board has hit.
          Cowering in fear, he attempts to scoop up her scattered 
          belongings.
          He persists.*
All dialogues are to be removed only event description remaining. 
Please help!

Comment: This question is not clear. Do you have fixed amount of spaces at the beginning of every event description line? Or, you have an empty line before and after every event description line?

Comment: Yes there is an empty line before and after every event description line. Also the dialogues are indented. You may check the script here. Thanks for replying. http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/10-Things-I-Hate-About-You.html